# How to detect on which row button in a listview user clicked

Tags: android, listview

Hello I have a `listview` in which I am using custom adapter & cutom layout of rows. I have like `imageview` at the top then bottom of it one checkbox at left end and button on right end.

Now I want to apply checked listener on `checkbox`and click listener on `button`. Here is this I am doing

```
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
});

satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
       if (isChecked){
           // perform logic
       }
   }
});
```

### Question

So in a listview there would be `checkbox` and `buttton` in each row. How would I know user click on second or third etc row `checkbox` or `button`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this answer by blackbelt:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851687/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android

good luck!

Comment: @Souto No don't want to apply itemclicklistener on listview. Instead of it, in a rows there are views like a button and checkbox in each row and i am trying to apply click listener on them & detect on which row button user clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some ways to do this. My prefferred method is by adding `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to your `checkbox's` holder in your custom view class, in `getView` method.

You can use `position` parameter in the `getView` to get the current row position.

Comment: If I scroll the list at the end & click on top row then I don't think I will get the position of clicked checkbox or button.

Comment: @Williams You will get it :) Because getView called multiple times

Comment: Suppose on a screen there is 9 rows and `getview` call 9 times here. when I click on 7th checkbox listener then `getview` won't call on click it then what position value I will get

Comment: the position in your onClick will be 7, it will be fired. I used this method for my projects, with very long listview and its working fine.

Comment: @Williams Its not that hard to move your code to the custom adapter, why dont you try it? Post your custom adapter code if its still not working

Comment: @Williams look at the 1st answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946110/set-onclicklistener-in-getview-with-viewholder-class Thats how i did it

Comment: @Williams Great :) I dont recommend other ways that involved doing "findviewbyid" to your views in each list item (bad performance). I think this solution is the best for performance